# What is going when nfds=0 in the select() system call

Tags: c, linux

I am debugging an application on Linux. And it has a couple of threads that are periodically calling the `select` system call:

`strace` shows:

```
select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {1, 342414})
```

So `nfds=0`. I thought that nfds is the highest file descriptor number occurring in any of the sets `readfds`, `writefds` and `exceptfds` incremented by one. It cannot be standard input (`fd=0`), because this would then have `nfds=1`.

So what is the meaning of `nfds=0` in this case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually `select` sleeps until either the timeout expires, or an event occurs on one of the file descriptors. If there *are* no file descriptors, the timeout is the only remaining behaviour.

My local manpage for `select(2)` even includes the text

> Some code calls select() with all three sets empty, nfds zero, and a non-NULL timeout as a fairly portable way to sleep with subsecond precision.

Comment: If this is a way to implement sleep behavior. I wonder when this should be preferred over a simple sleep() call. They are both posix compliant calls.

Comment: You mean: you wonder when the _fairly portable way to sleep with subsecond precision_ should be preferred over `sleep(unsigned seconds)`? I'd say it's when you want to sleep, but not for a whole number of seconds. HTH.

Comment: Ah select offers a more fine-grained timeout. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Note that the descriptor sets are all null pointers. In that case the first argument isn't really used and `select` is simply used to put the thread to sleep. For `1` second and `342414` microseconds (unless there's a signal interrupting the sleep).

Answer (score 2):

The `nfds` argument is not the largest descriptor, it is the largest + 1. So if you watched `stdin` with a file descriptor of 0, you would need to pass in 1.

Effectively `select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {1, 342414})` says there are no file descripts, and the actual file descriptor sets are pass in as NULL so they are note even checked. So only the timeout will have any effect in this call.